# Why does the jQuery element[] selector not work in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have lots of form inputs with automatically generated IDs which look like the following:

`<input type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_rptVariants_ctl00_txtQuantity"  />`

If I use the following jQuery selector, it finds the element:

`$("#ctl00_ctl00_rptVariants_ctl02_txtQuantity").val("666");`

However if I use either of the following, no element is found, yet all the documentation implies that it should work:

`$("element[id='ctl00_ctl00_rptVariants_ctl02_txtQuantity']").val("666");`

or

`$("element[id$='_txtQuantity']").val("666");`

The goal is to select all input fields where their IDs end in _txtQuantity.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks people - I'd misunderstood the page I was reading and thought that "element" was to be taken literally, not that I had to replace it with the type of element. They should have put it in italics or something!  I can't actually find the official documentation for this selector (It's hard to google "jquery element selector" - too generic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `element` refers to the tag.

In this case use `input`

like this:

```
$("input[id$='_txtQuantity']").val("666");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since they are not `<element>` tags but `<input>` ones, you should use:

```
$("input[id$='_txtQuantity']").val("666");
```

However, since `id`s are unique, this should suffice:

```
$("[id$='_txtQuantity']").val("666");
```